# Had William Sadler ever been considered for a role in The Walking Dead?

Tags: the-walking-dead, production

The Wikipedia article on [Frank Darabont](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Frank_Darabont#/Recurring_collaborators), original executive producer of *The Walking Dead* (TWD) explains that he works regularly with some actors. For example,

- Jeffrey DeMunn participated in many of Darabont's movies and portrayed Dale in *TWD*. He is known to have left the show in protest of Darabont's eviction during Season 2.
- Laurie Holden (Andrea in TWD) had a part in *The Mist* and *The Majestic*.
- Jon Bernthal (Shane in TWD) appeared in *Mob City*. The same can be said about Andrew Rothenberg (Jim).
- Melissa McBride (Carol), and Juan Gabriel Pareja (Morales) appeared in *The Mist* before being in TWD.
- Gregory Nicotero participated as a special makeup effects creator to TWD and *The Mist*. He also camoed in TWD as several walkers.

A notable exception is William Sadler, who was in *Shawshank Redemption*, *The Green Mile* and *The Mist*, but not in TWD.

**Was William Sadler ever considered or approached to play a part in *The Walking Dead*?**

Any word of God (or any of His angels) on the question?

Comment: Can we start a petition to get William Sadler in TWD, please?

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach: seeing what they are doing with the show these days, this would not be a service to William Sadler...

Comment: I am not sure I understand the downvote. Could the downvoter explain?

Comment: Those are all Stephen King adaptations, so perhaps Sadler is attracted to the combination of Darabont doing King material ... not Darabont on his own.